# curl_init undefined?

Tags: php, curl

I am importing the contacts from gmail to my page .....

The process does not  work due to this error

> `'curl_init'` is not defined

The suggestion i got is to

1. uncomment destination curl.dll
2. copy the following libraries to the windows/system32 dir: `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`
3. copy php_curl.dll to windows/system32

After trying all these, I refreshed my xampp, but even then error occurs.

This is my page where I am trying to import the gmail contacts:

```
<?php
resource curl_init  ([  string $url = NULL  ] )

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
?>

<?php
echo "hi";

if($_POST['submit'] != '') {
    echo "hi";

    $clientlogin_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";


    $clientlogin_post = array(
    "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
    "Email" => $_POST['Email'],
    echo "Passwd" => $_POST['Passwd'],
    "service" => "cp",
    "source" => "tutsmore/1.2"
    );


    $curl = curl_init($clientlogin_url);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clientlogin_post);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $response = curl_exec($curl);



    preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
    $auth = $matches[1];


    $headers = array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth);


    $curl = curl_init('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=10000');


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $feed = curl_exec($curl);


    echo "contacts".$contacts=array();


    $doc=new DOMDocument();



    if (!empty($feed)) $doc->loadHTML($feed);


    $xpath=new DOMXPath($doc);


    $query="//entry";
    $data=$xpath->query($query);

    foreach ($data as $node) {


        $entry_nodes=$node->childNodes;


        $tempArray=array();


        foreach($entry_nodes as $child) {


            $domNodesName=$child->nodeName;

            switch($domNodesName) {
                case 'title' : { 
                        $tempArray['fullName']=$child->nodeValue;
                    } break
                    ;
                case 'email' : {
                        if (strpos($child->getAttribute('rel'),'home')!==false)
                            $tempArray['email_1']=$child->getAttribute('address');
                        elseif(strpos($child->getAttribute('rel'),'work')!=false)
                            $tempArray['email_2']=$child->getAttribute('address');
                        elseif(strpos($child->getAttribute('rel'),'other')!==false)
                            $tempArray['email_3']=$child->getAttribute('address');
                    } break
                    ;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($tempArray['email_1']))$contacts[$tempArray['email_1']]=$tempArray;
        if(!empty($tempArray['email_2'])) $contacts[$tempArray['email_2']]=$tempArray;
        if(!empty($tempArray['email_3'])) $contacts[$tempArray['email_3']]=$tempArray;
    }
    foreach($contacts as $key=>$val) {

        echo $key."<br/>";
    }
}
else {

    ?>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="Email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="Passwd" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">tutsmore don't save your email and password trust us.</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Contacts" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This code is completely provided for debugging; if any optimization is needed, I will try to optimize the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new php file - like temp.php - and just add:

```
phpinfo();
```

It should give you information of your entire PHP configuration. Scroll through the installed libraries and see if cURL is there. If not, hit the Manual - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php - and get it setup. The instructions there are pretty good.

Comment: But what to do if cURL is installed. Console command `php -r "echo print_r(curl_version(), true);"` runs correctly. But can not call `curl_version()` from code.

Answer (score 36):

to install curl with php, you just type the command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

after your install php

Comment: It seems he's using windows, not linux.

Comment: to complete this I had to `php5enmod curl` and to `service apache2 restart` on debian

Comment: php5-curl is gone

Answer (score 3):

with linux:
`sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`  (php5-curl is gone)
then restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)

also for command line php, for composer and such, simply adding `sudo apt-get install php-curl` will work because I 'think' its acting on its active version

Answer (score 2):

`resource curl_init  ([  string $url = NULL  ] )`

Does this really appear in your source code?  If so, comment it out, as it's just documentation of curl_init's return type and arguments.

Now, if curl is still giving you trouble at this point, you need to check in `php.ini` and make sure `extension=php_curl.dll` does not have a `;` in front of it.  (I can't tell if that's what you meant by your first comment or not.)  Then use XAMPP to restart Apache.

Answer (score 1):

For xammp server, go to your **php.ini** file and remove the `;` mark from the beginning of the below line -

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

restart your apache server, now its will work fine :)..

Answer (score 0):

I use this code block to learn if a client's host/server has curl installed or not

```
$ci=@curl_version();
$cv=$ci["version_number"];
if($cv) echo "curl installed";
else echo "curl is not installed";
```