# Call to undefined function curl_init(), but I uncomment extension=php_curl.dll

Tags: php, curl

I have this error but I uncomment this extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini

Comment: and does php_curl.dll exist?

Comment: I restart apache, and php_curl.dll exist in this patch C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that the wamp curl module has a bug in the 64bit version. I had the same problem here.

**Look here:**
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85716

Take the curl module and replace it with your existing module (If you have the 64bit version) i have replaved the module in the 32bit version, too. But then you need an other module. Use the TS (Thread Safe) version. I hope you use the 64bit version.

Comment: Then you should replace the module. After that curl was working well.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you retart apache and mysql - if you're not sure how, a reboot will sort that. also check that `extension=php_curl.dll`  are uncommented in your php.ini for both php and apache folder before restarting and that the dll file actually exists in your build.

Comment: I uncomment in both php.ini files. and I restart all services. But I have still this error. I use wampserwer 2.2

Answer (score -1):

Create a new php file - like temp.php - and just add:

```
phpinfo();
```

It should give you information of your entire PHP configuration. Scroll through the installed libraries and see if cURL is there. If not, hit the Manual - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php - and get it setup. The instructions there are pretty good.

As posted by: [CaseySoftware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41752/caseysoftware) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2997860/1169669)